# .zip file got corrupted while scp through 2 linux servers

Tags: linux, ssh, zip, scp

A .zip file was copied by scp command from a Linux server to another Linux server and the zip file got corrupted and showed the following message.

"Unzipping the list file failed. Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream"

Please tell me under what circumstances a .zip will get corrupted while travelling through the servers.

Comment: File corruption would happen if there was lots of packet loss

Comment: I dont think Packet loss is the case.....Can u suggest anything else

Comment: The likeliest reason is that you tried unzipping before the transfer was complete. You should wait until the `scp` command finishes, it may show `100%` but if the `scp` has not exited, the transfer is not finished.

Answer (score 1):

Circumstances of file corruption:

- Cosmic rays
- Someone pulling the cable out and replug it
- A faulty switch / router
- A faulty cable
- A faulty cpu
- A faulty piece of ram
- A combination of all of the above.

The fix: retransfer the file. Until the checksum of the file on one machine matches the checksum of the originating machine.

Comment: If this info is helpful or not i dont know but then also i am writtng...
A .zip file while getting transferred from Campaign Management Service(CMS) to Blaster(Deployment Engine) through scp got corrupted....So the blaster was not able to read that zip file and the error was produced..

Comment: And so one of the circumstances mentioned above took place. Then go over to step 2, the solution: retransfer the file, check the checksum (sha1, sha256 etc). If the filetransfer is faulty again, try other means (cables, other servers). If it's still faulty: check the machines in question for bad ram, bad disks, bad network cards etc.